# How to set Flipper in a WSL2/React Native project environment?

Tags: android, react-native, wsl-2, fbflipper

I tried to find a guide in Flipper docs when using WSL2 but they don't have it.

How can I make it work when I already have a adb server running, a React Native Metro server running and a local node express server running?

Just to be clear, the React Native setup with WSL 2 is working fine, I just want to add Flipper.
The problem is that Flipper seems to try starting another adb server to listen on ports 8096 and 8097.

I'm not sure why I did that but I tried to run `adb reverse tcp:8096 tcp:8096` and `adb reverse tcp:8097 tcp:8097`, and Flipper initialized fine, since it ran adbkit when failed to run a adb server. It seems buggy but it is kind of working, and I don't know if I did the right thing..
Can anyone help me with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I known it is a bit but in case someone comes around the solutions is to assign the host 0.0.0.0 to metro bundler when you start it.

```
react-native start --host 0.0.0.0
```

you can find more on this [discursion](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1291#issuecomment-789756412)